# Summarized the resultset like following in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table as

```
ID,      Name  ,  atricle , price 
1  |     ajit |   phone |   20 
2  |     arif |   phone |   30 
3  |     arun |   mobile |   50
4  |     sandy |   mobile |   70
5  |     rocky |   car|   100
```

I want the result set as

```
ID,      Name  ,  atricle , price 

phone 

1  |     ajit |   phone |   20 
2  |     arif |   phone |   30 

mobile 

3  |     arun |   mobile |   50
4  |     sandy |   mobile |   70

car

5  |     rocky |   car|   100
```

I did what i want by 1st use distinct to article ,get all the article, did while loop, and then inserted records, with `where artcle='@artcle'`

But I want a single SQL query to achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand this question: can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: i want a single statement sql queries to get the desired result set

Comment: What is your desired result set? All the records are the same but you split it into what?

Comment: you need headings too??

Comment: What you want is a *presentation* problem. Your query provides you with data only, it's the presentation layer of your project that should take care of the output formatting. Consider using a reporting tool for that.